# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied Python

Tags: python, webserver

Hi I am trying to create a web server with python but I am getting an error message PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

This is my code:

```
import os, sys 
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

webdir = '.'
port = 80

os.chdir(webdir)
srvaddr = ('', port)
srvobj = HTTPServer(srvaddr, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
srvobj.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try changing the port to 8080.  You didn't say which OS, but most UNIX derivatives will only allow `root` to listen on ports below 1,024 or 4,096 depending on the OS and its configuration.