# Cannot instantiate python BaseHTTPServer on https port (443) [Errno 10013]

Tags: python, windows, http, ssl, basehttpserver

`BaseHTTPServer` cannot be instantiated with port 443.  I guess this is prevented to avoid collision with some other `https` services.

Therefore, I've tried to define SNI to this server using the following code, but it still fails...

Here's the server establishment code , I ran it from Windows `cmd` with administrator rights:

```
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("192.168.22.23", 443), MyRequestHandler)

tls_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2) 
tls_context.load_cert_chain(certfile='./cert.csr') 
tls_context.set_servername_callback(verify_tls) 
httpd.socket = tls_context.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, do_handshake_on_connect=True, server_side=True)

httpd.socket.settimeout(30) 
httpd.serve_forever()
```

here's the command that fails :

```
httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("192.168.22.23", 443), MyRequestHandler)
```

and the output :

```
c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.pyc in __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate)
    415         if bind_and_activate:
    416             try:
--> 417                 self.server_bind()
    418                 self.server_activate()
    419             except:

c:\python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.pyc in server_bind(self)
    106     def server_bind(self):
    107         """Override server_bind to store the server name."""
--> 108         SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
    109         host, port = self.socket.getsockname()[:2]
    110         self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)

c:\python27\lib\SocketServer.pyc in server_bind(self)
    429         if self.allow_reuse_address:
    430             self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
--> 431         self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
    432         self.server_address = self.socket.getsockname()
    433

c:\python27\lib\socket.pyc in meth(name, self, *args)
    226
    227 def meth(name,self,*args):
--> 228     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    229
    230 for _m in _socketmethods:

error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

any idea how to define my server on 443 without getting this error ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BaseHTTPServer cannot be instantiated with port 443. I guess this is prevented to avoid collision with some other https services.

Yes, the error *"error: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"* indicates such a problem.

> Therefore, I've tried to define SNI to this server using the following code, but it still fails...

The problem is not at the TLS layer at all and thus doing something at this layer (i.e. SNI) will not help. The problem is at the TCP layer: it cannot bind to port 443 because this already in use by some other process. The only way to fix this is to make sure that there is no other process using this port.

Comment: So the SNI can be used only when a single process is listening on 443, and the client request for specific service via SNI, right ?

Comment: @Zohar81: basically correct. But it is actually possible to have multiple processes listen on the same IP:Port if they share the listener socket or if the sockets are specifically designed to allow multiple bindings on the same address (`SO_REUSEPORT` socket option in UNIX). And the client does not request a service using SNI, but it requests a domain (although each domain might mean a different service in a particular implementation).

Comment: Hi again, perhaps do you know how to remove the listener I've got on the https port 443 in the following example from my windows machine ? `c:\>netstat -a -b | findstr 443
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            mycompuer:0            LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:443          mycompuer:54973        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54429        mycompuer:54430        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:54430        mycompuer:54429        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.50.113:54437   40.67.254.36:https     ESTABLISHED`

Comment: @Zohar81: I have no idea what you have as listener on port 443. Maybe you have an IIS there running, in this case see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+iis+window).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port to 8080. You didn't say which OS, but most UNIX derivatives will only allow root to listen on ports below 1,024 or 4,096 depending on the OS and its configuration. From this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16928146/7534176 answer.

Or run the command using sudo.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help, I've added to the question that I'm using windows and run this from `cmd` with administrator rights. it actually did work on port 4339 so the assumption on small ports doesn't catch here... can you think of something else ?

Comment: Also notice that the error here is different ([Errno 10013])